# How to cast the "Numberdrum" problem mathematically

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I came across the [numberdrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k4Ks.png) problem in the *Evening Standard*, where the objective is to obtain a number in the centre using each of the numbers in the outer ring exactly once, along with the four basic arithmetic operations.

Is there a way to cast this problem mathematically? I was thinking about an optimisation problem, but here we need to optimise over the operators in a way, which leads to a clumsy optimisation. Is there a neater method to solve this problem and find if its infeasible or not? Or find the closest value to the central number you can reach by using basic arithmetic operations on the outer numbers?

[image: Numberdrum]

Comment: Aren't there eight numbers in the outer ring? Or is the solver supposed to choose a subset of either size 5 or size 7 from the outer ring, to combine and obtain the center number?

Comment: @coffeemath: Sorry for the gaffe. No subset selection; all numbers in the outer ring must be used once.

Comment: Can you combine arbitrary numbers or must they be adjacent? Say, can you start with $367-171$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Any combination will do; but need to use a number just once. And only +/-/*/÷...

Comment: Well, it's a *finite* problem ... :)

Comment: Even if you are only allowed to use addition and subtraction, this is a difficult problem, known in the complexity-theory literature as PARTITION, and known to be NP-complete (meaning, it is unlikely that there is anything much better than exhaustive search).

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson... Could you add in that with a some more details about PARTITION for an answer?

Comment: @Shyam There are some optimization algorithms to solve this. Still interested in the solution? I can work during weekend about this...

Comment: @AnilBaseski: Would love to hear about them :)

Comment: @Shyam I tried to solve the problem with GA. Up to 5 variables the system is very stable. Starting from there I tried to optimize cross-over and mutation methods. Up to now I could not come up with stable parameters. 2 out of 100 trials converges with 8 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Going around from the 155:
$$155+7-2-367+15+42+171+56=77.$$
A program to check only sums of $\pm a$ would be only size $2^8=256.$

Comment: That's true here, but in general how do you solve for $N$ numbers in the outer ring? Gerry says it's NP-complete and that was what I wanted to know :)

Comment: Actually I was surprised no multiplication or division was required for this particular puzzle. I agree it's not very efficient for general $n$ ring size to check $2^n$ cases, so exponential in the ring size. And the size of the check would be even larger if multiplication/division are thrown in, since then also permutations of the ring numbers would have to be involved. And if parentheses are allowed it gets worse.